# Icon is not showing up in Qt Main Window

Tags: qt, qt5

My Qt application contains a Main Window. I added resource into project and added an icon to the resource. From the main window source file I used the following line to load the icon to the main window.

```
this->setWindowIcon(QIcon("://img/Icon.ico"));
```

When I run the application from Qt creator, it shows the icon in the mainwindow BUT when I run the exe from the executable path directly(copied all Qt dependency dlls into that folder) it is not showing the icon in the main window.

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Did you copy image plugins to the imageformats direcrory when you deployed your app?

Comment: I think when you run the standalone application it fails to find the qico.dll plugin to read the image file (.ico).

Comment: Can you show me your .qrc file please ?

Answer (score 2):

Put `qico.dll` in the `imageformats` directore near executable.

```
MyAppDir\YourApp.exe
MyAppDir\imageformats\qico.dll
```

On future, every format except of `png` should have dll. For example `qgif.dll` and so on.