# Qt5 app icon does not show up on Windows 7

Tags: windows, qt5

I have a Qt5 app. Icon is resides in Qrc file which is embedded to exe as cpp (as you know). On my local pc (Windows 10) i can see icons on tray and also on forms title. But on Windows 7 same exe does not show my icon.

Does anybody know why this might be happening? It's the same .exe I execute on 2 PCs.

Note: Windows 7 shows empty/blank tray and standard windows exe icon on title. But exe' s icon is normal. (on explorer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Reference**:
>   [Icon is not showing up in Qt Main Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679623/icon-is-not-showing-up-in-qt-main-window)

This solved my problem.